# Rewrite URL and get value from url in JSP

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

How can I rewrite my JSP URL , for example:

`myhost/UserMVC/index.jsp?id=5&&name=tome`

to

`myhost/UserMVC/index/5/tome`

and then get the `5` and `tome`?

Comment: The resulting URL is a REST-like URL. You should be dealing with REST-like things then.

Answer (score 1):

Use this UrlRewriteFilter http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ and write rules like this.

```
<urlrewrite>
  <rule>
    <from>^/UserMVC/index/(.*)/(.*)$</from>
    <to>/UserMVC/index.jsp?id=$1&&name=$2</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

In some case you need to use outbound-rule tag. UrlRewriteFilter has nice documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml, you choose what listens to which URL pattern. You do that when you define the mapping inside `WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stackoverflow.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any HTTP request that goes to /test/* will be handled by TestServlet. In that class you can use the HttpServletRequest to get access to the context path.

```
public class TestServlet implements javax.servlet.Filter{
    // ...
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest hReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String path = hReq.getContextPath();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


}
    // ...
}
```

Now you can handle path whichever way you like. As @Tiny suggested, you are probably better off using a REST framework like [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) though.